# pyplot plots different outputs in Spyder and iPython notebook

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot pseudo-random 2D-Gaussian data, so I'm using the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
mean = [0,0]
cov = np.matrix([[1,4], [4,6]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 10000)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], color = 'red', s = 1)
```

Ran on Spyder, it gives what I expect [image]

Ran on an iPython notebook, it gives a much "sharper" ellipsis

[image]

Any idea what's happening here ?

Edit: I just realized my covariance matrix, though symmetric, is not definite positive. But even if this is wrong, why the different outputs?

To answer questions in comments, I am sure I am using the same covariance matrix (just checked again). And I am indeed using `%matplotlib inline` in my notebook, that's the only difference in the code.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same covariance matrix in both plots? Judging from the covariance matrix, I would say that second plot seems more plausible. I find it hard to judge how the plot should look like, since covariance is not normalized. The pearson correlation between the `x` and the `y` dimension is almost one, so I would say the second plot makes more sense.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem with Notebook.  Are you using `%pylab inline` or similar, to put the plots in-line?  Without inline magic, I get a plot like your first one, in a new window.  If I use `%pylab inline` or `%matplotlib inline` I get the same thing, but in the browser output.

Comment: Thanks for your help : see my answers in latest edit.